# Drupal change display based on vocabulary

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, taxonomy

I need to have terms related to a specific vocabulary use a custom view I have set up.

For example: I have a vocabulary called "Book Categories" with terms under it such as Humor, History, etc. When navigating to a term page (taxonomy/term/7), I would like to display just the book title and a custom book-cover field. By default, Drupal displays node title, teaser, and links on all taxonomy term pages. The problem I am having is I would like terms that fall under the "Book Categories" vocabulary to use my custom view, and all other terms to use the default view.

Is there a way around this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone default taxonomy view and change fields section as you like.
In PAGE SETTINGS->PATH remove "%" and add taxonomy number of your Book Category (like "7") 
In contextual filter delete all filters.

This view then should override default view.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new module called [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) that seems like it does what you want to do. Try it.